# DataTables: Disable drag and drop table columns

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am using the [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin on my table. An issue I am experiencing is I can drag and drop a table header to move the column to another position.

I want to disable this. I've been Googling and looking thrugh the docs but I cannot find an answer.

Here's my code

```
<script>
var oTable = $('#report_table').dataTable({
    "paging" : false,
    "sDom": 'RC<"clear">lfrtip',
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aaSorting" : [],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sInfo": "" //Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ results
    }
});
new FixedHeader(oTable);
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have **dataTables.colReorder.js** script included perhaps? If so, remove `R` letter from `sDom` option.

Comment: That's fine :-) glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was per @phillip100's comment:

Do you have dataTables.colReorder.js script included perhaps? If so, remove R letter from sDom option.